# Creating a new column for historical information on a time-sensitive dataset in pandas

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I want to create a new dataframe that groups by 'id' and creates a new column for everything on and before 2016. Effectively, I am trying to flatten the dataframe below. 
Here is the original dataframe:

```
Year | id | issue_1 | issue_2
=====|====|=========|========
2014 | 11 | 1       | 0
2015 | 11 | 0       | 1
2016 | 11 | 1       | 0
2014 | 15 | 1       | 1
2016 | 15 | 0       | 0
```

Note that it is possible to skip years, as shown by id=15 which doesn't have any 2015 data.

My aim is to get the final output to look like this:

```
id | 2016issue_1 | 2015issue_1 | 2014issue_1 | 2016issue_2 | 2015issue_2 | 2014issue_2
===|=============|=============|=============|=============|=============|=============
11 | 1           | 0           | 1           | 0           | 1           | 0
15 | 0           | 0           | 1           | 0           | 0           | 1
```

Comment: does my method answer your question?

Comment: Yes, this worked well. Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try .pivot_table (see code and output below).

```
df = df.pivot_table(index=['id'], columns='Year', values=['issue_1','issue_2'])
```

[image]